# : Unresolved reference: VERSION_11 in android Studio Giraffe

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi am using android studio giraffe am I finished i tried to run my application but I keep on getting this error
**e: C:\Users\FYA TEAM\AndroidStudioProjects\fya_hooks4change\app\build.gradle.kts:36:39: Unresolved reference: VERSION_11**

I think it might be the java version I have tried to update to the newest but still getting the same problem

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj2Hr.png)

Thanks in advance

am not able to run the application

Comment: Please do not post code of configuration file content as screen shot. What gradle version is used by the project?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

you have to use JavaVersion.VERSION_11 instead of using VERSION_11 directly. and dont mind my java 1.8 configuration. its just there to show you a working example. Therefor i added java 11 version below it.